# UserID vs Username performance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

Is it better to store an integer UserID or store Username as the key.

Which is better for performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions seems more like a discussion because it's really based on application requirements. However, I will give a general answer why UserID is better for performance.

My 3 reasons why UserID is better for performance:

1. Can be auto incremented saving one less trip to database to check if Username is in use.
2. Allows for users to change usernames
3. Unsigned `INT` data type only requires up to **4 bytes** allowing up to **4294967295 unique ids**

My 3 reasons not to use Username:

1. Storage, using an UTF-8 charset will require **3 bytes** per character or **1 byte** per character for something like `latin1`
2. For maximum lookup speed, you have to use `MyISAM` table with fixed-width tables. A fixed-width table on `MyISAM` gives you a **30% increase** in lookup speed versus a dynamic table.
3. `MyISAM` does table level locking which can cause *slower performance* if table is a heavy `write`.

Comment: MyISAM tables don't support transactions and are generally worth avoiding.

Answer (score 1):

As long as both fields are primary keys the performance will be the same.

Comment: Which is a better practice if it is used a lot as foreign keys

Comment: @atombie if you are going to use it as a foreign key then I would definitly recommed using userID makes the relationship clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The performance will be the same but I would use UserID as an auto incremented primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Ideally most websites have both UserId and Username and both of these are meant to be unique. 
When you assign UserID, then you can auto increment it and that ensures that each new entry into the table gets a unique userID and it does the job for you. 
However, I am assuming you are not planning to have users use the userID as a means to access your website coz that would just be bad design.

Answer (score 0):

In the long run, usernames will be more complex than an automatically incremented Id integer.
You might not notice much difference in performance of the comparisons MySql makes, but your  domain code might benefit from being able to compare ID numbers rather than strings containing usernames.

If you want to be able to fetch data by username with comparable performance, yet not make the username a primary key, take a look at MySQL's indexing

[Here is a good article on indexing.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm)